# How do I create an ArrayListMultiMap?

Tags: java, multimap

I am trying to create a new MultiMap. But my code is not building correctly

```
import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
```

```
  error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayListMultimap(no arguments)
    [javac]         Multimap<Integer, String> multimap = new ArrayListMultimap<Integer,String>();
```

and

```
  error: cannot infer type arguments for ArrayListMultimap<>
    [javac]         Multimap<Integer, String> multimap = new ArrayListMultimap<>();
```

and

```
  create cannot be instantiated to type
```

```
Multimap<Integer, String> multimap = new ArrayListMultimap<>();
Multimap<Integer, String> multimap = new ArrayListMultimap<Integer,String>();
Multimap<Integer, String> multimap = new ArrayListMultimap.Create();
```

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://guava.dev/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html). This class does not offer any constructor, do not try out random things. See the static methods, there are 3 variants of `create` (not `Create`).

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
ListMultimap<Integer, String> confMappings = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

as it seems to use a create method to return an instance.

Side note: methods in java use camel-case where the first letter is lowercase. You have used Create() instead of create().

Comment: Note that this is just a naming convention, people *can* use a different style for their methods (not that they should though).